# How to get all data in pagination by url

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, pagination

I have a problem that i want to iterate pagination from the API, i want to make export function but using pagination, and my problem i confused how to iterate it, the API have pagination.

```java
private Document getProcessInstances(String status, int page, int size, String sort) {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

    url.append(activitiqueryhost)
        .append("/v1/process-instances?status=")
        .append(status)
        .append("&page=")
        .append(page)
        .append("&size=")
        .append(size)
        .append("&sort=")
        .append(sort);
    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>> URL=" + url.toString());

    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> processinstancestring = this.get(url.toString());        
        System.out.println("processinstancestring=" + processinstancestring.getBody());
        Document processinstance = Document.parse(processinstancestring.getBody());
        System.out.println(">>>>> processinstance=" + processinstance.toJson());
        Document processinstancelist = (Document) processinstance.get("list");
        System.out.println(">>>>> list=" + processinstancelist.toJson());
    }

    return processinstancelist;
}
```

[SOLVED]
thanks for the question, i have solved this problem, so i made a new method for get totalItems from the pagination,and iterate it.

Comment: Please, specify what means *make export function but using pagination*?

Comment: for example, i want to get data from API... and the API have pagination... i want to get all data using iterate pagination by url... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, If I understand it correctly. So for example, if you need to paginate the result which you get from your data store. You need to follow below 2 steps

1. Obtain the Pageable object that specifies the information of the requested page.
2. Pass the Pageable object forward to the correct repository method as a method parameter.

As per spring docs, 
On top of the CrudRepository, there is a PagingAndSortingRepository abstraction that adds additional methods to ease paginated access to entities [(doc link)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

In your Controller class, you can form the Pageable Object and pass it to the Repository.

Also, you can set 
`spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size=5` in your application.properties to set default size of your page.

You can try running below project and see if it helps

https://github.com/sidd081/spring-boot-sampless